# What is the fastest way to turn an object's public properties into JSON

Tags: php, json

My use case:

- Select 500 rows from a database using PDO.
- Turn off emulation mode to fetch native data types
- Use `fetchObject('ClassName')` to fetch the rows

Now that I have an array of 500 populated objects I want to turn this into JSON a.f.a.p.

Currently I am using the following method:

```
function get_object_public_vars($object) {
   return get_object_vars($object);
}

class Model implements \JsonSerializable {
 public $property1;
 public $property2;
 private $property3;

 public function jsonSerialize() {
   return get_object_public_vars($this);
 }
}
```

Then I do

```
// $dbStatement is a PDOStatement with a MySQL select query prepared
$a500objects = $dbStatement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Model');
echo json_encode($a500objects);
```

Now I did some tests and if I instead do `$dbStatement->fetchAll();` without the `class_name` argument. the code runs much faster and this scales when selecting more rows.

However I need 'Model' objects to implement some application logic. It seems running `get_object_vars()` 500x is taking its time. (even with OpCache)

Does anyone know a faster way to parse objects of class 'Model' to JSON?

Comment: use fetchAll()?

Comment: though I am not sure I understand your problem and whether it's even related to PDO

Comment: The "slow part" of the code is when turning into JSON or fetching as object?

Comment: here you are talking about serializing an object and here you are talking about fetching a record. here you are writing  `$a500objects` which suggests an array of 500 objects and here it's fetchObject('Model'); where it returns a single object

Comment: The PDO part is quick, The query takes about 1ms. I am using `fetchObject()` in a while loop. I should have written `fetchAll()` in my example. The difference in performance is when fetching as a 'Model' It must go through the `jsonSerialize()` and `get_object_vars()` Which is where must time is spend when I profile this.

Comment: so basically your question is "why get_object_vars() is so slow"?

Comment: No, question is: is there a faster way than my current use case. Maybe a cast or a union type.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this?

```php
 public function jsonSerialize()
 {
     return 
        [
            'property1' => $this->property1,
            'property2' => $this->property2,
            'property3' => $this->property3,
        ];
 }
```

Comment: I tried this to see if `get_object_vars()` was slow. To my surprise it performed the same.